# Trying to geolocate bounding boxes in an image

Tags: geolocation, annotation

I'm currently trying to geolocate bounding boxes that I draw on an image (images contain trees, I'm trying to annotate and geolocate the individual trees). I have had no success yet in finding methods to do so. I did find an interesting [paper](https://tropicalconservationscience.mongabay.com/content/v6/TCS-2013_Vol_6(4)_506-520_Lisein.pdf) and tried to use the Image footprint projection method, however that seemed to be a dead end. All images are taken looking down, from a drone and all images contain relevant exif data regarding the location, altitude, pitch etc. Any recommendations on how to I could tackle this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Orthorectify your images https://gisrsstudy.com/orthorectification/#:~:text=Georectify%20take%20an%20image%20that,due%20to%20topographic%20variation%20corrected. and then you should be able to heads-up digitize using the orthophoto as a reference in your GIS software of choice.

Comment: To ad on the comment from @MichaelStimson the next step you would need to look for is "georeferencing". It's very easy to implement in QGIS and you will find many youtube tutorials with the search "QGIS georeferencer".

Comment: Orthorectify your images and use a supervised image classification to identify trees.  The resulting classification will be geospatially located.  See here for ArcGIS:  https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-e&q=arcgis+supervised+classification&safe=active  and here fo QGIS:  https://www.igismap.com/image-classification-in-qgis-supervised-and-unsupervised-classification/

Comment: The quality of autogeoreferencing of drone images based on GNSS and IMU data varies  with the quality of the sensors.  Even in ideal conditions (flat ground under the UAS) the quality of the autogeoreferencing degrades as altitude increases.  https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gerry-gabrisch-gisp-2aa3263b_algorithm-based-automated-georeferencing-activity-6910658166561153024-M1gy?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop